# How to force Animate to work properly?

Tags: animation

I would like to animate a simple clip where the points appear at a plot

```
LIN = {};
Animate[Poin1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]; 
 LIN = Append[LIN, {Poin1}];
 TableForm[{{n}, ListPlot[LIN, ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> Red] }], {n, 1, 5, 
  1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> .5 , 
 DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

The code should result in the plot with increasing number of points, from 1 to 5. At the end,
the plot should have 5 static points.
But in fact, the points are being added in a continuous manner.

[image]

When I stop the animation at t=2, the points continue to appear. This looks like the animation works in a non-stop mode

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

LIN = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 5];

Animate[
 ListPlot[LIN[[;; n]],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 {n, 1, 5, 1},
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
 AnimationRate -> .5,
 DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The points are adding up because you do nowheer reset LIN to an empty list.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
LIN = {};

fun = Function[{m}, If[m == 1, LIN = {}];
  AppendTo[LIN, RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]]]

Animate[
  ListPlot[fun[n], ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> Red]
 , {n, 1, 5, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> .5]
```

You will see that the animation does not exactly stop after 1 iteraion. It makes some additional steps. Why that is, I do not know.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, this woks, when the points list is generated in advance. But there exists a side effect, at least, for me: `n` varies from 1 to 5 as needed, then returns to 1, 2, and again returns to 5. In brief, I see steps: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,5 :((

Comment: I saw this too, but I do not know the reason.